# random forest vs support vector machine on image processing

Tags: image-processing, machine-learning, classification, random-forest

I recently worked on the image recognition. One data point consists of one feature vector `x` and its label `y`.  Image features I used are like this: gist, color histgram, HOG. I vectorize these features and put them together to form `x`. For the label `y`, it can only be one of 21 labels.

Then I split the whole dataset into two parts randomly. And I trained classifier on part one and tested the accuracy on part two. The classifiers I used are random forest and support vector machine. 
But the results show: for random forest, the training accuracy is 0.99 while the testing accuracy is 0.73; for support vector machine, the test accuracy is 0.20.

Could any one tell me why they are so different?

Comment: Well the following does not explain the decrease in accuracy, but LIBSVM (if you are using it), then it does one-vs-one classification and Random forest is a natural multi-class classifer. Still, I don't see the reason for such a difference in two accuracies. Few questions: 1. What is the training accuracy for SVM? 2. Did you try using tuning cost and gamma parameter, and the kernel of SVM?

Comment: It sounds strange for me that the SVM performance are so low. Did you use train_auto() in openCV or parameter selection tool grid.py of libsvm ?